# Define an "alternate" login domain for Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, login

A buddy asked me this question - and I quite honestly don't know enough about Active Directory and how to operate/configure AD to answer this.

A customer of my buddy has an AD domain `DomainA` and that's what's they use to sign on to Active Directory now - users sign in with their user name in the form of `DomainA\John Doe`.

For whatever reasons (don't ask me for those reasons!), they know what to logon with a **different** domain name (which is **not** a subdomain of the first domain) - let's say `OtherDomain`. So the idea is: the Active Directory still runs on `DomainA`, but the users log in using `OtherDomain\John Doe`.

Any chance this is even possible? If so: how do you set this up / configure such a scenario?

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible. [It's called a UPN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739093(v=ws.10).aspx) and can be whatever you want.

In Active Directory Domains and Trusts you can define a new UPN for your forest. It then becomes select-able on the Account tab of a user account in ADUC. So if your domain is `Domain1` and you define `domain2.whatever` as a UPN suffix for a user, that user can log in as `user@domain2.whatever`

Comment: OK - but can they log on as `domain2\user` (NetBIOS-style), too? Or only using the UPN name `user@domain2.whatever` ??

Comment: That, I'm not 100% user about. You can change the NetBIOS name for a whole domain, but I don't believe that changing the UPN for a user will allow that specific format to work.

Comment: UPN only affects the "@" style name. You can't change the NetBIOS style login.

Comment: @ChrisS: OK thanks - what if I had a second domain `OtherDomain` and established full, two-way trust between both domains. Could users log on to `DomainA` using `OtherDomain` accounts?

Comment: If you had two domains DomainA and DomainB, with trusts, users from the trusted domain can log-in to the trusting domain. But users still can't use the "wrong" domain in their login credentials. So if users exist in DomainA, they *can not* login using "DomainB\User" as they still don't exist in DomainB.